# apply a function across columns

Tags: r

I usually face problems with dataframes that have many columns.

For example, trying to calculate the Mann-Kendall test:

```r
library(tidyverse) 
library(Kendall)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Season, ~Luxembourg, ~Germany, ~France, ~Russia, ~USA, ~Spain,
  "Summer 2000",          29,       88,      NA,      NA,   31,     10,
  "Summer 2001",         134,       36,      23,      NA,   37,      4,
  "Summer 2002",          22,        9,      10,      NA,    7,      3,
  "Summer 2003",          40,       11,      19,      NA,   16,      6,
  "Summer 2004",          74,       19,      26,      NA,   27,      9,
  "Summer 2005",          16,        8,      14,      NA,    8,      4,
  "Summer 2006",         191,       22,      32,      NA,   32,     16,
  "Summer 2007",          15,        7,      13,      NA,   14,      4,
  "Summer 2008",          43,       48,      22,      NA,   27,     14,
  "Summer 2009",          16,       35,      14,      NA,    7,      9,
  "Summer 2010",          29,        8,      25,      18,   11,      7,
  "Summer 2011",          10,        4,       6,      12,    3,      3,
  "Summer 2012",          55,       33,      11,      17,   46,     23,
  "Summer 2013",          62,       57,      23,      70,   45,     21,
  "Summer 2014",          65,        7,       6,      21,   12,      7,
  "Summer 2015",          74,       11,      43,     110,   21,     11,
  "Summer 2016",          85,       35,      79,      89,   30,     20,
  "Summer 2017",          NA,       11,      12,      14,   10,      6,
  "Summer 2018",          NA,       22,      11,      30,   18,     12,
  "Summer 2019",          NA,       20,      11,      25,   NA,     14
)


Mk_Luxembourg <- MannKendall(df$Luxembourg)
Mk_Germany <- MannKendall(df$Germany)
Mk_France <- MannKendall(df$France)
Mk_Russia <- MannKendall(df$Russia)
Mk_USA <- MannKendall(df$USA)
Mk_Spain <- MannKendall(df$Spain)


Mk_results <- as.matrix(bind_rows(unlist(Mk_Luxembourg),
                                  unlist(Mk_Germany),
                                  unlist(Mk_France),
                                  unlist(Mk_Russia),
                                  unlist(Mk_USA),
                                  unlist(Mk_Spain)))
row.names(Mk_results) <- c("Mk_Luxembourg", "Mk_Germany", "Mk_France", "Mk_Russia", "Mk_USA", "Mk_Spain" )   

Mk_results                               
#>   country        tau     sl     S     D  varS
#> 1 France     -0.113  0.527    -19  168.  810.
#> 2 Germany    -0.0697 0.696    -13  186.  942.
#> 3 Luxembourg  0.171  0.364     23  134.  586.
#> 4 Russia      0.244  0.371     11   45   125 
#> 5 Spain       0.280  0.0965    52  186.  941.
#> 6 USA        -0.0529 0.779     -9  170.  815
```

This becomes very tedious when instead of 6 I have 70 variables.

Is there a simpler way to call all the variables at once?

Comment: Look up the differences between "long" and "wide" data, and the concept of tidy data.

Comment: get your data tidy, and then summarize it with mannkendall. See the package tidyverse for it !

Comment: This dataframe is already tidy. No need to be rude.

Comment: @SantiagoI.Hurtado the data is tidy. See the package tibble to get why!

Comment: Thanks @user3808394 for the review :) Truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like following

```
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Season = c("Summer 2000","Summer 2001",
             "Summer 2002","Summer 2003","Summer 2004","Summer 2005",
             "Summer 2006","Summer 2007","Summer 2008",
             "Summer 2009","Summer 2010","Summer 2011","Summer 2012",
             "Summer 2013","Summer 2014","Summer 2015","Summer 2016",
             "Summer 2017","Summer 2018","Summer 2019"),
  Luxembourg = c(29,134,22,40,74,16,
                 191,15,43,16,29,10,55,62,65,74,85,
                 NA,NA,NA),
  Germany = c(88,36,9,11,19,8,22,
              7,48,35,8,4,33,57,7,11,35,11,22,
              20),
  France = c(NA,23,10,19,26,14,
             32,13,22,14,25,6,11,23,6,43,79,12,
             11,11),
  Russia = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             NA,NA,18,12,17,70,21,110,89,14,30,
             25),
  USA = c(31,37,7,16,27,8,32,
          14,27,7,11,3,46,45,12,21,30,10,
          18,NA),
  Spain = c(10,4,3,6,9,4,16,
            4,14,9,7,3,23,21,7,11,20,6,12,14)
) -> df

library(Kendall)

#Apply the MannKendall function across the columns 
try <- lapply(df[-1], MannKendall)

#Convert list to data frame
do.call(rbind.data.frame, try)

#                   tau         sl   S        D     varS
# Luxembourg  0.17101437 0.36358595  23 134.4916 586.3333
# Germany    -0.06971737 0.69586229 -13 186.4672 942.3333
# France     -0.11311328 0.52717423 -19 167.9732 810.3333
# Russia      0.24444444 0.37109327  11  45.0000 125.0000
# USA        -0.05294209 0.77930272  -9 169.9971 815.0000
# Spain       0.27963457 0.09646106  52 185.9570 941.3333
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a case where the traditional (cbind, apply...) syntax looks better than the tidyverse's:

```r
library(Kendall)

# tidyverse
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Season, names_to = "country") %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarise(x = list(enframe(unlist(MannKendall(value))))) %>%
  unnest(x) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)

# traditional
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(df[-1], MannKendall))
```